# Conservative Systems and The Hamilton-Jacobi Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics

I am trying to understand geometrically the relation between a conservative classical system described by the hamiltonian $H$ for which the trajectories of particles are given by
$$\dot{x} = \nabla_p H(x,p) \qquad \dot{p} = - \nabla_x H(x,p)$$
and that of the Hamilton-Jacobi equation
$$u_t - H(x,\nabla u) = 0.$$

Namely: the trajectories of particles with hamiltonian $H$ are constrained to level sets of that hamiltonian. Are these level sets related to the characteristic curves given by the corresponding Hamilton-Jacobi equation? Is there a direct way to go between the level sets to the characteristic curves or vice versa?

You may restrict the problem to 1 space dimension if necessary.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The function $u$ is known as [Hamilton's principal function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation#Action_and_Hamilton.27s_functions). Since OP's system is apparently [autonomous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics)), one should (in order to simplify) use [Hamilton's characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation#Separation_of_variables) $W$ instead. The [HJ equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation) then simplifies to 
$$H(x,\nabla W)~=~E. $$
The corresponding [characteristic curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Fully_nonlinear_case) certainly preserves the energy level $E$.